# speech-commands project: error Command "train" not found

Tags: javascript

I'm going to use convent to complete a simple audio classification task. This is a model based on tensorflow.js - speech-commands, and the code that defines and trains the password convent is located in the tfjs-models repository. I need to download the password dataset before training, I have downloaded and decompressed the dataset, but before I want to start the training process, I get an error, the error is error Command "train" not found.

I've tried adding the line train:node train.js to the package.json file in the speech-commands directory.

Comment: Please create a [**`minimal reproducible example`**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.